# Docker Is there a way to verify that a container belongs to a particular image build?

Tags: docker, update, containers, kolla-ansible

I am a newbie in the containers world.
From what I have read, when you want to update your container you do this :

1. Stop the container.
2. Delete the container
3. Pull the new image
4. Recreate the container, and now you are running the new version of the image.

My problem is like this, I used kolla-ansible to deploy Openstack, to update the images, the documentation here (https://docs.openstack.org/kolla-ansible/yoga/user/operating-kolla.html) says that, I have to :

1. Update kolla-ansible package.
2. Pull the new images
3. And finally execute kolla-ansible deploy

In my deployment I am using a local registry, so my update operation goes like this :

1. Update kolla-ansible package.
2. Pull the new images.
3. Tag the new images in the local registry
4. Push the new images to the local registry
5. Finally execute kolla-ansible deploy

Which I did, but when verifying the containers, I see that they haven't been restarted.
I know that an image contains a build date in it.
Is there way to tell that : this container comes from this image build.
I need a way to be sure that my containers have been updated. That they are using the new images, the new code.

Regards.

Comment: The image used is shown in `docker ps`. If the containers have not been restarted they are not using the new images.

Comment: When you pull images you can tag them with new tag like `yoga-new` and then inject in local repository and change `kolla_release: yoga-new` something like that then kolla will pull new images which has tag yoga-new